# Youtube videos in jQuery dialogs always on top of other content

Tags: css, flash, youtube, z-index, video-embedding

I am having some troubles embedding videos in a jQuery dialog. It displays and plays all well but it is always in front of other dialogs. When I pass another dialog over the one with the video the video stays on top of everything... Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with jQuery or JavaScript.  It has to do with the z-index of a Flash object.

I've used this solution before with success...

http://manisheriar.com/blog/flash_objects_and_z_index

- Put your Flash content into a wrapper `div` called `flash`
- Add `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` to your `object` tag
- Add `wmode="transparent"` into the `embed` tag
- Use CSS to set the `position` and `z-index` for your `div` (don't set negative z-index values as it will hide your Flash)

**CSS**

```
#flash {
    position: relative; /*or absolute*/
    z-index: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="flash">
    <object .... >
        <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
        <embed .... wmode="transparent">
    </object>
</div>
```